# In Airflow, how do I execute a task only if my Variable.get("ENVIRONMENT") = "PROD"?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Example:

There are 2 different environments: development and production.

```
**IMPORT <everything>
env = Variable.get("ENVIRONMENT")
...
...
...
default_args...
WITH DAG(
dag_id = '...',
catchup= False,
schedule_interval= '00 4 * * *',
)
a = BigQueryOperator(
task_id = '...',
sql = '''
SELECT * FROM ...
''',
destination_dataset_table = f"{project_id}:data.table"
write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
allow_large_results = True,
use_legacy_sql = False,
)
b = BigQueryOperator(
task_id = '...',
sql = '''
SELECT * FROM ...
''',
destination_dataset_table = f"{project_id}:data.table"
write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
allow_large_results = True,
use_legacy_sql = False,
)
c = BigQueryOperator(
task_id = '...',
sql = '''
SELECT * FROM ...
''',
destination_dataset_table = f"{project_id}:data.table"
write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
allow_large_results = True,
use_legacy_sql = False,
)**
```

The question is: How can I run tasks a and c on both environments, but b only on the productive environment?

Thanks!

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by running on both environments? Do you mean running the operator twice with different SQL?

Comment: @Elad, exactly. The SQL Statement is the same, but it generates a sample on development and another on production, so the values are not the same. I want to generate it only on production and another dag will copy the table and paste it on development, so we'll be able to study.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish what you want:

1. Read the variable while parsing the DAG file and only create the task b if the variable is set to the correct string value. This could be done with a simple conditional in the DAG.
2. Use a ShortCircuitOperator to skip task b based on the value of your variable.

Comment: Reading airflow variable out side of operator scope is bad practice. Do not do this.

Comment: @Elad Would you mind elaborating on why that is bad practice?